# Localize chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, localization, chart.js, offline

(I don't want to use node, and npm)

I want to download chart.js on my own machine, so I can run it offline. I downloaded the cdn from [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.3.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js). I import it like this, in html:

```
<script type="importmap">
        {
          "imports": {
            "three": "./vendor/three.module.js",
            "gltf": "./vendor/GLTFLoader.js",
            "chart": "./vendor/chart.umd.min.js"
          }
        }
</script>
```

but then in an example chartComposit.js file I can't use it, as it throws me this error:
`chartComposit.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'chart' does not provide an export named 'default'`

In js I import like this:
`import Chart from 'chart';`

This same method worked with three.js so I don't understand, why it does not work like this here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why not use this `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>` as in their docs?

Comment: Becasue I specifically said, I don't want to use that, as this will have to operate offline?.... You could have just given me an answer.

Comment: you can download it from there, then include it locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up the import line. Here is the correct one: `import * as m_chart from 'chart';`

Comment: Yes, for me it did!